# hombrew install show up "curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server "

Tags: homebrew

when i install hombebrew itself,

i keyin
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
in my terminal.
then,

in my terminal pop up:

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.